# Where will the record get inserted first?

Tags: oracle

I have a schema called "**CUSTOMERS**". In this schema there is a table called **RECEIVABLES**.

There is another schema called "**ACCOUNTS**". In this schema, there is a table called **RECEIVABLES_AC**.

RECEIVABLES_AC has a public synoym called RECEIVABLES. 
The table structure of both the tables is exactly the same.

If your front-end uses the customer schema credentials to establish a connection, how can you ensure that the record will get inserted in RECEIVABLES_AC without changing the front-end code.

**I think this is a trick question.** Short of renaming the table RECEIVABLES in the CUSTOMERS schema, I don't see how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I can think of (without changing the login or insert statement) is to use a database trigger that runs on login and changes the current schema to ACCOUNTS:

```
create or replace trigger logon_set_schema
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   if sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER') = 'CUSTOMERS' then
      execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema=accounts';
   end if
END;
/
```

However, this would likely break other aspects of the code, so changing the application to specify the schema name would be vastly preferable.

Answer (score 0):

What isn't specified is if the behavior is supposed to be instead-of or in-addition-to.

1. Use replication on `ACCOUNTS.RECEIVABLES` to propagate DML to `CUSTOMER.RECEIVABLES_AC`.  Triggers, streams, what have you.
2. Use the `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA` statement to change the default namespace of the user's session.

The right way to respond is to fix the design, and to not have multiple receivables tables with public schemas floating about.

Comment: I am not sure where you're going with the REPLICATION bit. Since the data in the two tables doesn't have to be same.

I believe the alter session is useful, if fired on a logon trigger.

Comment: Since this is an interview question, I'd strongly suspect that setting CURRENT_SCHEMA is the answer they're looking for.  I second abhi, though, that I don't know where you're going with the replication approach.

Comment: @abhi:  That the data in the two tables doesn't need to be the same was not specified, and it was noted that the two tables had identical structures.  Part of such interview questions is not making assumptions that "data goes here" implies "data does not go there."

Answer (score 0):

Two good ways to solve this problem are:

**Option 1**

1. Rename `CUSTOMERS.RECEIVABLES`.
2. Drop the public synonym.
3. Create a private synonym in the CUSTOMERS schema, called RECEIVABLES that points to ACCOUNTS.RECEIVABLES_AC.

**Option 2**

1. Change the front-end to refer to RECEIVABLES_AC instead of RECEIVABLES.
2. Create a private synonym in the CUSTOMERS schema, called RECEIVABLES_AC that points to ACCOUNTS.RECEIVABLES_AC.

I would prefer Option 2. Private synonyms are a great way of controlling which tables are used by a particular schema, without having to hard-code the schema name in the app.

Comment: Renaming CUSTOMERS_RECEIVABLES is the option that I suggested. Once that has been done, the public synonym will take care of the pointing business.